# What does "embraced its re-discovered freedoms with gusto" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Reading [**this article**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/not-covid-kazakhstan-first-country-105755703.html), there is a line,

> But Kazakhstan, home to 18 million, **embraced its re-discovered freedoms with gusto.** Family-oriented Kazakhs went back and forth to see relatives, and police would routinely bust wedding parties of up to 100 people as large gatherings were still banned. Cafes and gyms were busy again, and borders were opened to ease travel

Since I would not like to make this question so long, I take the meaning "embrace" as "to welcome or accept eagerly : attach oneself to : avail oneself of readily", and gusto as "vitality marked by an overabundance of healthy positive and often unrefined vigor and enthusiasm".

My questions are:

1. Is my understanding of each term correct?
2. What does the bold line mean **in the context of the whole line?**

Comment: Lockdown was lifted -- it only lasted for two months.  That lockdown meant the Kazakhs lost certain freedoms.  Lifting that lockdown meant that they could find those freedoms again -- these are re-discovered freedoms.  The next couple of sentences contain examples of *how* the Kazakhs embraced its re-discovered freedoms: by visiting family members, by having over-sized weddings, by returning to public venues, by crossing borders.  The first sentence is a general statement. The rest of the paragraph are examples of what the general statement meant.  The following paragraph contains the results.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The "freedom" in “*embraced its re-discovered freedoms*” refers back to when the country did not have any cases of COVID 19 and people could ***do*** what they want.

Before the pandemic; children went to schools, employees went to their workplaces, families celebrated weddings, people met up with friends, attended outdoor and indoor music concerts, watched movies in the cinema, and supported their local football team in stadiums etc. All very normal activities that everyone took for granted *before* the disease COVID 19 infected the world. In Kazakhstan,  large ***social gatherings*** were  forbidden by the government. In other words, with the lockdown the aforementioned *freedoms* were suppressed.

Once the lockdown was lifted, the 18 million people of Kazakhstan resumed  all the activities and events that had been denied to them with **renewed gusto** (enthusiasm). The term "re-discovered" is used metaphorically, the author explains that the population RETURNED to experiencing the joys of social gatherings.

Comment: Wondered why this question had been lifted for a while..^^

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Your understanding of the meaning of *embrace* in this context is correct.

The basic sentence is:

> Kazakhstan embraced freedoms.

*re-discovered* is a past participle acting as an adjective and says "what types of freedoms?":

> Kazakhstan embraced re-discovered freedoms.

*its* is a possessive pronoun and explains, "who's 're-discovered freedoms'?". The antecedent is *Kazakhstan*:

> Kazakhstan embraced its re-discovered freedoms.

*home* is an appositive phrase which is a way to restate the preceding noun (like a predicate nominative would do, but with the verb "to be"):

> Kazakhstan, home, embraced its re-discovered freedoms.

*to 18 million* is a prepositional phrase that modifies *home*. "what type of home?":

> Kazakhstan, home to 18 million, embraced its re-discovered freedoms.

*with gusto* is a prepositional phrase that modifies *embraced* and describes "how it was embraced?":

> Kazakhstan, home to 18 million, embraced its re-discovered freedoms with gusto.

*But* is a conjunction. Grammatically not needed, but it helps to link this sentence with the preceding sentence to make the meaning clear:

> But, Kazakhstan, home to 18 million, embraced its re-discovered freedoms with gusto.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough teaching. Now I have an agony with the linguistic words such as antecedent, predicate in the context. Thank you anyway.

Comment: So in overall, are you saying the bold line (including other lines) indicates that Kazakhstan is **preparing for** the new freedom?(which is, lockedown is now "loosened"?).

Comment: @Kentaro よし、日本語の英文専門用語にしよう。(#1) No. This is not about "the new freedom". This is about more than just one "freedom". (#2) These are "re-discovered freedoms", not "new freedoms". "Re-discovered" means 再発見。(#3) Why do you think "preparing for ...."? All verb tenses (動詞時制) are in the past tense (過去形). In the past, they "re-discovered freedom". Now, they still have them. (#4) But, I read the article. It looks like they will take away the freedoms, but this has nothing to do with this grammar issue.